# Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()

Tags: validation

validation rule saving problem DM__c this is text field.

```
   AND( $RecordType.Name ="Policy Variation Request",ISPICKVAL(Case_Sub__c,"Migration Extension"),ISBLANK(TEXT(DM__c)))
```

error :  Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text

Comment: I've downvoted this question because the error is quite straightforward, and you have shown no attempt at research or solving your own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already mentioned that your field "DM__c" is of type text, you need not to wrap it around TEXT() method.
Just replace ISBLANK(TEXT(DM__c)) by ISBLANK(DM__c).